# How building bazel with the bazel without a `--compilation_mode opt` flag affects performance?

Tags: bazel

[Bazel documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-compile-source.html) suggest two ways of building the bazel from the source code:

1. `bazel build //src:bazel --compilation_mode=opt`
2. `bazel build //src:bazel-dev`

Documentation says, that the first one:

> yield a smaller binary but it’s slower to build.

but is there any performance advantage, or maybe that option affect only size?

Answer (score 1):

Bazel (4.0) consist internally of client and a server. The client (fronted) is small and communicates with the heavy Bazel sever (backend). The tiny client is written in C++ and the heavy Bazel server (backend) is written in Java.

`--compilation_mode=opt` affects only C/C++ code-generation. An optimized build runs usually always a lot faster then a debug or fast-build. So yes it makes sense to use this option and yes the client will the run a "bit" faster. The heavy work is done in the Bazel server which is written an Java.